# Unexpected behavior of `class<-`()

Tags: r

I'm having troubles in understanding the difference in the following codes :

**First piece :**

```
a <- 123
class(a) <- 'FOO'

b <- a
class(b) <- 'BAR'

class(a) # returns 'FOO'
class(b) # returns 'BAR'
```

**Second piece :**

```
a <- 123
`class<-`(a,'FOO')

b <- a 
`class<-`(b,'BAR')

class(a) # returns 'BAR' ! so class attribute has been replaced  also on "a"
class(b) # returns 'BAR'
```

As far as I know, `b <- a` should create a copy of `a`, not immediately, but as soon as `b` is modified.
But looking at the second case, it seems that using `` `class<-(x,"") `` function (which I expected to be just the *non-syntactic sugar* of `class(x)<-""`) the copy is not created and the original object is modified instead.

Am I missing something (maybe in the documentation) ?

*Tested in R version 3.2.5*

Comment: In previous versions, as Tomas notes, `"class<-"` indeed seems to ignore any >1 references of an object and modifies it. Generally, though, calling directly a (builtin) `"fun<-"(x, value)` form of function, unless coercion is needed or the argument is multi-referenced, the original argument should change, while interpreting `fun(x) <- value` will always reflect the change in "x" (even if coercions/copies are made). Also, see the classic example of `a = 1:2; \`*tmp*\` = "tmp"; exists("*tmp*"); class(a) = "foo"; exists("*tmp*")` and changing the "class() = " with `"class<-"(a, "foo")`

Comment: Yeah, I'm well aware that `class(a) <- "foo"` is actually translated as : `'*tmp*' <- a;a <- 'class<-'('*tmp*', "foo");rm('*tmp*')`. Still, the bug remains... but, good to know, seems to be fixed in new versions :)

Comment: Well it would be more correct to have `b <- 'class<-'(b,'BAR')` in the example, because of the value semantics of R, to let an (non-broken) version of R do the copy.

Comment: @digEmAll : The difference is that the intermediate `"*tmp*"` seems to be used only in the `fun(x) = value` call, which prepares the argument appropriately based on its references before being passed to the internal function. The `"fun<-"(x, value)`, I guess, calls the replacement function directly and that function may or may not take into account the references of "x" relying on the fact that the creation (and passing as argument) of `"*tmp*"` accounts for any copies to be made. Here, the "bug" was that `class<-` did not account for its argument's references but relying on `"*tmp*"`.

Comment: @TomasKalibera: yep, that's correct

Comment: @alexis_laz: that's a possible explanation of the bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an R bug present in older versions of R. A recent version of R-devel already works as expected - the object is not modified in place. It was fixed in R-devel version 70636.

Please note that the example is not quite correct. Because of the value semantics of R, functions are not allowed to modify their arguments in-place (except environments). Therefore, functions like `class<-` have to modify a copy of their argument, and they return this copy, so the example should have used `a <- 'class<-'(a,'FOO')` instead of just `'class<-'(a, 'FOO')`.

When a replacement function (like 'class<-') is implemented in R, there is no way of violating the value semantics. But, in an assignment like `a <- 'class<-'(a, 'FOO')`, we see that the old version of 'a' without the attribute set will not be used again. For efficiency, many replacement functions are implemented in C and they violate the value semantics of R by modifying their argument in-place, but **only** when it is known that the value of that argument is not used by any other variable. Incidentally this optimization had been (re-)added to `class<-` in the respective version of R.

I believe that the function `'class<-'` (and similar) should not be called directly by R programs. In this simple case it should be as simple as described in the question, but in general mapping replacement calls to calls to functions like `'class<-'` is more complicated. Also, the implementation currently differs between the AST interpreter and the byte-code interpreter. More information can currently be found in [R language definition (for the AST interpreter)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) and in [compiler documentation](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/compiler/compiler.pdf), but those are implementation details that R programs should not rely on. R programs should always use the `class(x)<-` form.

Comment: Actually, I've never read anywhere that you shouldn't use the functions in the form `'foo<-'(x,y)` ... do you have some references ?  Anyway, thanks for the information, I didn't know it was a bug...

Comment: My 3.2.3 has this bug, but my 3.3.1 doesn't, but I can't see a relevant bugfix between those versions in : https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html (doesn't mean its not there though...)

Comment: @digEmAll the suggestion not to use the form `'foo<-'(x,y)` is mine, I am not sure if it is stated anywhere in documentation - I have modified my answer to make it clear (and expanded a bit).

Comment: @TomasKalibera: I agree that for readability sake and from a idiomatic point of view, using `foo(x) <- y` is absolutely preferable. Still, I (rarely) use the other construct (e.g. in one-liners) and since it's not stated anywhere that `foo<-()` has to be avoided, I think the different behavior of the two variants should be considered a "bug" (as it is).
Anyway, thanks again for information in the answer :)